# Reference request for the terminology and usage of different types of plasmas

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, plasma-physics

I'm looking into discharge models, specifically for *combustion prcesses*, and I'm swamped by the number of different types of plasmas and their respective treatments (thermal plasmas, non-thermal plasmas, different degrees of inoization, excitation levels, diluted systems, etc. etc.).

I'm looking for an overview, maybe in form of a dedicated review, which gives a characterization of these different types, probably also in terms of temperatur(es). I'm not sure how standardized the terminology in this field is at this point.

In the end I would like to find out which of these types is used in which applications (i.e. in which practical engineering designs). A comment on the respective model approaches would then be very helpful too.

Comment: I studied plasmas with this book: M. Moisan et J. Pelletier, "Physique des Plasmas Collisionnels. Applications aux décharges haute fréquence". It had a very nice classification of plasmas in the first chapter. Unfortunately it's in french so I do not know if it this be useful...

Comment: If you are looking for plasmas enhancing combustion processes, then, from an engineering point of view, your plasmas will probably be non-equilibrium discharge plasmas, ranging from glow discharges to arcs, with possibly High voltage nanosecond pulsed repetitive discharges too. The advantage of ultrafast discharges is very low energy consumption while creating a lot of radicals

Answer (score 3):

You can start with this very brief (13 page) survey by Tim Eastman : [A Survey of Plasmas and Their Applications](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20060026167_2006228298.pdf)

It provides some philosophical perspective and frames the field nicely. The bibliography can help you dive deeper, and probably the first place to turn is reference no. 8, Plasma Physics and Engineering by Fridman and Kennedy. You can read the first two chapters for free on the book's amazon page (it gives you a preview for the kindle version that you can read in your browser), which is fortunate since those chapters also provide an overview and help classify different aspects of the subject.